# Show this tree exists for n >= 3

Tags: graph-theory, induction, trees

I wonder if you guys can help me find an easier solution for this.

Show that for every n >= 3 a tree exists with exactly n nodes and n - 1
leaves.

My instructor had a solution that basically covered induction, constructing a new tree with a new node and edge, then counting its degrees and pove that the new tree is as acyclic and connected as the previous. I found this solution very extensive and was wondering whether there is a quicker and more efficient way.

So if there is one and you know it, maybe you can share...? ^^

Comment: Consider "star" like graph:).

Comment: haha... I would have liked to give that as an answer, but I do not know whether my professor will...

Answer (score 1):

Given $n$ nodes $v_0,\ldots, v_{n-1}$, let there be an edge $v_0v_i$ for $1\le i\le n-1$. Then $v_0$ has degree $n-1>1$, all other $v_i$ have degree $1$, the graph is connected (e.g. $v_i\to v_0\to v_j$) and acyclic (because only one node has degree $>1$).

Comment: Thank you for the answer... I have another question, namely, shouldn't there be some other steps before concluding that v0 has degree n−1 > 1? That part is not really clear to me... thanks...